# How to receive array data from post in php?

Tags: php

I am having a problem to receive array data from select option. Please see code below

Here is my html file

```
<?php

     $data = array(
             "id" => "1",
             "name" => "John"
     );

?>

<select name="member">
     <option value="`<?php echo $data; ?>`">John</option>
</select>
```

And here is my php file

```
$val = $_POST["member"];  
echo $val["id"];
```

Comment: Please try to re-word this question.

Comment: @CORRUPT you put an extra `$` at the beginning of your statement. var_dump is a function, not a variable.

Comment: `$val = $_POST['member']` is going to be a string, not an array. So `$val['id']` will fail.

Comment: you can not echo array like you are echoing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do really want to pass an array from a form, I strongly recommend you to use serialize function.

So in your code.

```
<select name="member">
    <option value="`<?php echo serialize($data); ?>`">John</option>
</select>
```

Then in your back-end,

```
$data = unserialize($_POST["member"]);
```

Try this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
<select name="member">
     <option value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
     <?php echo $data['name']; ?>
     </option>
</select>
```

Because in your code, you use `<?php echo $data; ?>` which does not print the value in array, but the string `Array` which is the type of variable.

Comment: Sorry for my code and my bad english. I just want an array in option tag and I will use index of it in backend

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ID and check on the server the other info.  Something like this (PHP FIDDLE)(http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mvr-zde)

Comment: Your fiddle won't work on the second submit, best check that.

Comment: I intended it for 1 submission. just re-add the data under the if statement if you'd want it to be show again.